# Interlock (only enable one object of same type)

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my task:
I need to instantiate some objects of the same class. But only one object can be active (maybe accessing hardware) at the same time. Therefore I need to include some interlock in the class. I tried this like shown in following example.

```
class ModuleClass(object):

    _activeModule = None

    def __init__(self, aModuleName):
        self.ModuleName = aModuleName
    def activate_module(self):
        if self.__class__._activeModule == None:
            self.__class__._activeModule = self.ModuleName
            #activate module here
            print("%s active"%self.ModuleName)
        else:
            raise UserWarning, "other module active"
    def deactivate_module(self):
        if self.__class__._activeModule == self.ModuleName:
            self.__class__._activeModule = None
            #deactivate module here
            print("%s deactivated"%self.ModuleName)
        else:
            raise UserWarning
```

This class is imported at the beginning of a test run and instances of this class are used in the test run. The problem is now, that the test run could abort from any case. Then the test run is repeated automatically. And then I can not activate any object of *ModuleClass*, because the attribute *_activeModule* is not set to its default value.

How could realize this interlock to function also correctly if a test run is repeated?
(And I don't want to realize this with *try ... except* in the test run. Is it possible to manage this within the class or objects?)

Comment: The [_Singleton_ pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) might be appropriate. There are several ways to implement one in Python.

Comment: I don't think that this will work. Currently our framework initializes every module defined at the beginning of a test run. And during the test run single modules are activated and deactivated again.

Answer (score 0):

Write your activate/deactivate as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers):

```
class ModuleClass(object):
    _activeModule = None

    def __init__(self, aModuleName):
        self.name = aModuleName

    def __enter__(self):
        if ModuleClass._activeModule == None:
            ModuleClass._activeModule = self.name
            print("%s active" % self.name)
        else:
            raise UserWarning, "other module active"

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if ModuleClass._activeModule == self.name:
            ModuleClass._activeModule = None
            print("%s deactivated" % self.name)
        else:
            raise UserWarning
```

And use it like this in your test code:

```
module = ModuleClass("abc")
with module:
    print "using %s" % module.name
```

Output:

```
abc active
using abc
abc deactivated
```

The module will *always* be deactivated, even if an exception is raised within the `with` block.

Comment: This method is interesting and I tried it already. But does this also work without the *with*-statement? (The framework we use uses *try-except* structures.)

Comment: A context manager (`with` statement) is the way to to the equivalent of `try`\`finally` but encapsulated within the object being "acquired" and "released". Both of that concept and `try`\`except`are part of the python language itself.  If your framework uses `try`\`except` elsewhere, that won't really interact with what's going on here.